# Running GDB on C++ application from a Python Script (Automation)

Tags: python, gdb

I'm encountering quite a big frustration with one of my tasks. We're automating some of our processes and there's this step. Run a GDB command on the backed up core files. The command itself is rather  simple:

```
gdb --batch --quiet -ex "set logging overwrite on" -ex "set logging file gdb.out" -ex "set pagination off" -ex "set logging on" -ex "pwd" -ex "run" -ex "backtrace full" -ex "info registers" -ex "info threads" -ex "thread apply backtrace full" -ex "set logging off" -ex "quit" binary core
```

Now there are some echo in there to make the file more readable with some -ex "echo \n\nStuff:\n"... you can imagine. While this command works flawlessly when executed manually from a terminal window, I have to perform this from a python script. I thought I would just use subprocess module to my aid:

```
subprocess.Popen(['gdb', '--batch', '--quiet', '-ex', '"set logging overwrite on"'...], binary, core)
```

When I run this however, the commands after each 'ex' e.g. set logging overwrite on are not there. **GDB reports: Error unknown command ""** and no output file is created not even a file with null bytes, but this is kind of obvious.
I tried to use stdin to fed gdb with the inputs but that didn't work at all, I guess gdb doesn't use the standard input. Oh yeah... gdb module for python is not available in our organization on it's not that 'you should just install it' because I can't do that. So I'd prefer a solution for my exact situation. GDB with subprocess.

PS: I also tried to remove the logging file and read out stdout from the process... also didn't work. Either process.stdout.read() returned an empty string or when I could get something out the string contained 4 lines and the last 500 truncated.

Our python version: 2.7.3

Many thanks for any tips! (I'm officially out of ideas.)

@Edit:

Tried the put the commands in external file and use --command option to try to trick it. As a result, no logging file was created but instead the previously mentioned 5 lines was printed to stdout while the rest remained the same (nearly 500 lines truncated and lost in the echo)

By removing the quotes from around the commands seems to have some effect. The logging files are created however formatting for the gdb command is gone and gdb is stuck around run > app.out.

```
gdb --batch --quiet -ex set logging overwrite on -ex set ...... -ex echo ??Threads:? -ex info threads ...
```

BY looking into the running processes I can see a running gdb instance with the above command. looking into the out files I can see that gdb stuck at run > app.out while doing nothing. If I execute the command manually with quotes around the commands this **never** happens as I manually created the core file with kill -3 so no errors should prevent gdb to run the app till the end. Upon checking gdb with ... gdb (gdbception) the thread is in sigsuspend from /lib64/libc.so.6
This doesn't really tell much to me to be honest.

Comment: A workaround: why not try storing GDB commands in a file and use `--command` option?

Comment: Nearly the same result as before. GDB starts up. I get 5 lines printed to stdout, no file created with logging file and the rest 500 truncated. But this prints something to stdout! Advancing! Updating the original post.

Comment: Try it without the double-quote characters. By default, subprocess.Popen won't use a shell.

Comment: Seems to be working, but have to wait a bit to check on the generated files contains everything as expected. Yeah, so partially working Updating original post.